# Open healcode link in iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

The problem I am having is preventing a link from launching a new page and loading its href value in an iframe. The client site is using healcode a service that provides widgets to schedule fitness classes etc.Check this [page](http://iyengarnyc.org/brooklyn-institute-daily-class-schedule/) When you click the signup button after the widget loads it opens a new page. What the client wants is to open that link on the same page or in a popup window. I have tried everything I can think of. I have used jQuery,fancybox, etc.

HERE IS THE CODE IM USING
[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DrrQX.png).

What I think the problem is, is that my inline scripts loads before the widget scripts finish renders the the schedule html.

I know it is possible because [this site](http://www.889yonge.com/) uses the same widget and their signup opens the link in a overlay frame on the same page.

Please shed some light on this.

UPDATE:

```html
<html>
 <head>
  <title>Test</title>
 </head>
 <body>


<iframe id="openViewHere" width="500px" height="500px" src="" ></iframe>

<script type="text/javascript">
  healcode_widget_id = "7696499e81";
  healcode_widget_name = "schedules";
  healcode_widget_type = "mb";
  document.write(unescape("%3Cscript src='https://www.healcode.com/javascripts/hc_widget.js' type='text/javascript'%3E%3C/script%3E"));
  // Healcode Schedule Widget for Iyengar Yoga Association of Greater New York : Brooklyn Daily Class Schedule
</script>
<noscript>Please enable Javascript in order to get <a href="https://www.healcode.com" target="_blank">HealCode</a> functionality</noscript>



<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
        
 $(".signup_now").click(function(){
   
  var url = $(this).attr("href");
   
  $("#openViewHere").attr("href",url);
   
   
   
  return false;
 });

</script>



 
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: please provide a fiddle

Comment: here it is http://jsfiddle.net/f2sfzeg9/4/

Comment: where is your sign up button ?

Comment: After the widget loads the buttons appear on the page. It is generated by the healcode javascript. Visit the first link in my post that says page to see the button and widget

Comment: i cant get the healcode script to work anywhere the script itself has errors !

Comment: document.write does not work in JSFiddle copy the code locally and it works

Comment: i tried it localy doesnt work ! only blank page appears. no errors at all.

Comment: now it works please hold

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use this code :

```
$( document ).ready(function(){


    $("body").on('click',".signup_now",function(e){

        $(this).attr("target","_self")

            })

})
```

be aware that `windows.ready()` might fire , while the widget script is still adding elements dynamicaly that is why the listeners dont work , you have to access the element through already loaded parent ( e.g "body" ).